# Are there any exceptions to const char*?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, ostream

If `cstring` is a pointer, then why can it get a value directly? Secondly, Why wasn't the ‍‍‍`*cstring`'s result equal to whole of string? Third, `cstring` is a non-constant pointer to a constant character, so why change its value and not change its address?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const char* cstring = "string";
    cout << cstring << endl << *cstring << endl << &cstring << endl;

    cstring = "foo";
    cout << cstring << endl << *cstring << endl << &cstring << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cstriing` is a `const char *`, so its value is the address of a single `char`.   By the rules of the language (i.e. C and C++) when initialised with or assigned to a string literal, that address is the address of the first character in that string literal  (i.e. the `'s'` of `"string"` on initialisation, and the `'f'` of `"foo"` after the assignment).    Since `cstring` is a variable, it's address cannot be changed, but its value (assuming the `const` qualifiers are consistent) can be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `cstring` is a pointer, then why can it get a value directly?

Anyone can get the value pointed at by a pointer by dereferencing the pointer. That's what happens when you do `std::cout << cstring`. The proper overload gets chosen that prints the string represented by `cstring` assuming that is correctly formed, null-terminated C-style string.

> Secondly, Why wasn't the ‍‍‍`*cstring`'s result equal to whole of
>   string?

`cstring` is a `const char*`, so `*cstring` is a `const char`. Pass that to `std::cout` and it will call an overload that prints one `char`. The function that is called internally doesn't even know that this is just one `char` in a string.

> Third, `cstring` is a non-constant pointer to a constant character, so
>   why change its value and not change its address?

You can't change the address of a variable. `cstring` is in a fixed place on the stack. You change the value of `cstring`, which is the address of the string that it's pointing to (it is now pointing to a different string, which has a different address, `"string"` of course stil has the same address).

What you probably wanted to try is this:

```
const char* cstring = "string";
std::cout << (void*)cstring << std::endl;
cstring = "foo";
std::cout << (void*)cstring << std::endl;
```

Now you can see the different addresses. One is the address of `"string"` and one is the address of `"foo"`.

Answer (score 2):

> If cstring is a pointer, then why can it get a value directly?

The `operator <<` of `cout` for `const char*` is specialized to behave that way. It will treat the pointer as a NULL terminated string and will print it instead of the pointer value. For different types you get different behaviour. For `char*` you have the whole string printed.

> Why wasn't the ‍‍‍*cstring's result equal to whole of string?

That is because the type of *cstring is `char` and again, `operator <<` behaves correctly by just printing a single char. a `const char*` is essentially an array of char.An array is essentially a pointer to the first element of the array. If you use the `*` operator on a pointer you are accessing whatever the pointer points to. If it points to the first element, well, you get the first element.

> Third, `cstring` is a non-constant pointer to a constant character, so why change its value and not change its address?

As you said, `cstring` is a non-constant pointer to constant data. You cannot change the place it points to (it is a constant pointer), but you can substitute the content of the pointed data with other stuff. You point to the same location but the content of that cell changes.